# Can we put callback function inside dll?

Tags: c#, serial-port, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use .Net serialport methods from another program which uses Unity3D engine.

I've a c# class library (dll) that register and implement a callback function when the serial port receives some data.

```
public CSerialDll()
{         
   _serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serial_DataReceived);
}

void serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   int bytes = _serial.BytesToRead;
   _comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
   _serial.Read(_comBuffer, 0, bytes);
   Console.WriteLine("data recv: " + System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(_comBuffer));
}
```

And then in my another program, I create an instance of the class.

I want to know whether my call back serial_DataReceived inside the library (dll) will be called or not. I'm trying to read _comBuffer inside the library from another program and it always empty (even though the data are coming when I tested with a console app inside the same app).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<HUNCH>`

If I was a class designer, i would put the data into the callback, so if you look at the `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs` class, you'll see that inside it is you buffer with the data.

So, after you get an event, and you then call read, you actually discard the data that is sent to you and request more.

In other words, yes, the fact that it is an external library doesn't have anything to do with the fact it isn't working as it should.

`</HUNCH>`

Comment: That's the way I wrote my own serial port library, but from the looks of it, astk is using Microsoft's `Serial.IO.Ports` library which does actually force you to read the data after you get the event, it isn't attached to the event.  There are a lot of things done badly in the Microsoft `SerialPort` class, actually.

Answer (score 0):

There's typically nothing particularly special about methods being in a separate DLL, as long as access modifiers are set correctly.

However depending on how you set up your solution it can be a pain making sure you have the latest DLL in your bin folder.

Comment: It should work. But the problem is it doesn't. In my client that uses that dll, I create a new instance of that dll. So the dll will register the callback. As you can see in my above code, that callback fills _comBuffer which has a property to read from outside programs. And then in my update loop of my client program, I tried to read that property. This property is always empty. But when I make the dll project as a console app project and wrote a main method to test the code, I can receive the data from serial. Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: @astk So when you step through the code what are your observations. Also its worth mentioning that just because the code is in a separate dll doesn't mean you can't step through it.

Comment: Hi... how to step through? I'm using Unity3D as a client that uses that DLL. I could step through my unity script. But not at the dll source level. Thanks...

Comment: @astk You probably should have mentioned that earlier. I've updated the tags on your question but you should edit your question to include that you're using Unity3d. People don't always read the comments

Comment: @astk: Inside Visual Studio, build your dll and then start debugging.  Since you're debugging a dll and not an executable, it will ask you what program to run, at that point choose the unity3d main .exe file.  Visual Studio should then recognize when code in your dll runs and you should be able to set breakpoints and use watch expressions.

Comment: @Ben nice. I wasn't sure if you could do that. I also wasn't sure he has VS, since he could be talking about MonoDevelop

Comment: @Conrad: Well, any good debugger should allow that.  But Visual Studio Express Edition is free, so I'm willing to assume it is available.